# Node.js event proxy

Tags: node.js, express, event-handling, socket.io, zeromq

I currently have a solution that works, however I would like to remove redundant operations from my server code.

What I currently have in my express app is something like:

```
// create a ZMQ socket connection
var zmq_sock = require('zmq').socket('dealer').connect(ENDPOINT);

// On a new socket.io connection from a client, register that client as a listener
// to any zmq event, and unregister the client upon disconnect
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   var client_callback = function(id, msg) { 
     // some expensive operation
     socket.emit('data', json_data); // socket.io emit to the client
   };
   zmq_sock.on('message', client_callback);
   socket.on('disconnect', function() {
     zmq_sock.removeListener('message', client_callback);
   });
});
```

The problem is that with each ZMQ event, the expensive operation is being executed on a per client basis. What I'd like to do is somehow have an event proxy where by each client registers/unregisters itself with the proxy, and when a ZMQ event occurs, the expensive operation happens once and then the results are emitted to each client.

Is there an easy way to do this in node or a node module that helps tie the events together? Documentation, tutorial or an example would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the event emitter pattern.

```
//Event emitter pattern
var events = require('events');
function EventManager() {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
    this.wakeUp = function (message) {
        this.emit(message);
    }
};

var util = require('util');
util.inherits(EventManager, events.EventEmitter);
var manager = new EventManager();
manager.setMaxListeners(0); //max is now infinity
```

you can register for the event

```
 manager.on(callback);//callback is a function.
```

Once you define, you can throw an event using

```
manager.wakeUp(message);
```

Also, dont forget to unregister

```
manager.removeListener(callback);
```

Here is some more [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html)